# Is it possible to show two or three Forge screen in one browser tab?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to display two models in parallel on a browser.
Is it possible to show two or three Forge screen in one browser tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite straightforward.

1. Create two or three DIVs on the page and use CSS style to control their width or height.
2. Instance two or three Forge Viewer objects and use them to load the corresponding model.

Here are the samples:

- https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-viewer-samples/blob/master/public/aec-mapping-2d-to-3d.html
- https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-plant-operation